# iOS7 Style Lock Screen - HTML5 & CSS3

Tags: html, css, ios7

I am trying to recreate the look and feel of the iOS7 lock screen for my UI. See below for an example:
[image]

I am using some advanced CSS filters (http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur) to blur the background image.

```
-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
```

I then use an overlay that has its opacity set:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6)
```

To get started, I wanted to recreate the circular buttons. However, I am unsure how to get the "cutout" to the layer below working. Please see my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abehnaz/cpwvU/6/

Is there a clever way to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps a better way to ask this question would be to ask how I can properly use the alpha blending.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this question and css3?

Comment: I stopped working on this at the time. As of 10/15/2014, this may be possible. The new CSS Background Blend mode and CSS Filter could make Webkit (Chrome only?) able to do this. However, I think having this as a cross browser effect would be difficult.